# Page in Content of Child Window

Tags: silverlight-4.0, childwindow

I am a new bee to Silverlight and its controls, at present I am doing experiments with Child windows so at present this is my scenario,
I have created a child window by adding a child window  item my project,  to use it I have created an object like below

```
ChildWindow1 obj_ChildWindow1 = new ChildWindow1()
```

Generally we assign a content that we create in the respective child window, but I append different xaml page to its content by creating a new xaml page like below

```
Page2 obj_page2 = new Page2();
obj_ChildWindow1.Content = obj_page2
```

so that what ever controls and function I do on the page2 that are present inside the Childwindow, until now it is fine everything is working as per my guess, 
but how to close the child window after firing of some event in the page2,  how to do that?

Second point is how set the size of the Page2 with respect to the ChildWindow

Thanks in advance.......

Comment: Is my question is not clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer but I don't think that is the right way to approach,i sent the object of the childwindow and I received it in the Constructor of the page2, and close the Childwindow using that